# What are the steps to deploy an Angular 2 app in a .NET Windows environment?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, angular, devops

We are an ASP.NET shop using Windows Server, IIS, Octopus Deploy, etc. We do not use Azure.

In terms of structure and files, my Angular 2 app is very similar to this: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM%20-%20Final%20Updated. There is no .sln file or anything like that as it is not an ASP.NET app.

What steps should I take to deploy my Angular 2 app to a server?

My guess so far is to just to run these commands on the server directly from a command window:

```
 - npm install
 - npm run lite
```

Or maybe try create windows service to run these commands?

Answer (score 0):

You will deploy the way you normally do, but eventually what you're going to need to is to create a `dist` folder (or whatever you want to name it) that has all of your concat'd files / etc. This is what you'll eventually push to IIS etc. Your original Typescript / etc files of course will never get exposed.

How you get your files to a `dist` is up to you. You can use SystemJS, Gulp, Webpack.

I'd recommend Webpack personally. Basically nothing unusual, you just only want to expose (publically) those minified/concat specific files for Production. IIS just needs to know where they are, and how to serve the initial `index.html` (Also, up to you, MVC, .NET Core, etc)

Comment: Don't I still have to do "npm run lite"? The issue with running "npm run lite" is that I have to keep the command window open to keep the server running.

Comment: If you're using `npm run lite` and such, you want to open Task Runner Explorer, there you'll see your package.json and its **scripts**. You'll be able to run the `lite` script from there. Even better, right click it, and make it run after build / open / whatever you want.